# Passing logic of previous column as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a long query, here is a portion of it:

```
SELECT '3' AS RowType
    ,DTH.EnteredBy AS Person
    ,COALESCE(PDT.[Name], APP.AppName) AS Project
    ,(
        CASE WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                    ) THEN 'Kanban' WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                    ) THEN 'Sprint' ELSE SCY.Catagory END
        ) AS ProjectType
    ,dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number], ???) AS Theme
```

Where the ??? is, I am having a problem.

I need to pass the result of the previous column, that is:

```
CASE WHEN (
                        STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                        AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                        ) THEN 'Kanban' WHEN (
                        STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                        AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                        ) THEN 'Sprint' ELSE SCY.Catagory END
            )
```

WHat is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use 'Cross Apply' or CTE (Common Table Expression) to do this. I prefer Cross Apply so here is an example that way:

```
SELECT '3' AS RowType
    ,DTH.EnteredBy AS Person
    ,COALESCE(PDT.[Name], APP.AppName) AS Project
    ,CAResult.ProjectType
    ,dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number], CAResult.ProjectType) AS Theme
FROM [SomeTable]
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN (
                    KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                    AND SprintId IS NULL
                    ) THEN 'Kanban' WHEN (
                    KanBanProductId IS NULL
                    AND SprintId IS NOT NULL
                    ) THEN 'Sprint' ELSE Catagory END
        ) AS ProjectType) as CAResult
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either repeat the query, it will be executed only once, or you can use a sub-query/ CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT '3' AS RowType
    ,DTH.EnteredBy AS Person
    ,COALESCE(PDT.[Name], APP.AppName) AS Project
    ,(
        CASE WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                    ) THEN 'Kanban' WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                    ) THEN 'Sprint' ELSE SCY.Catagory END
        ) AS ProjectType
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT *, Theme = dbo.primaryTheme(Number, ProjectType)
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

A CTE is probably your best bet here.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT '3' AS RowType
  ,DTH.EnteredBy AS Person
  ,COALESCE(PDT.[Name], APP.AppName) AS Project
  ,(
    CASE WHEN (
                STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                ) THEN 'Kanban' WHEN (
                STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                ) THEN 'Sprint' ELSE SCY.Catagory END
    ) AS ProjectType
  FROM Table STY
)

select c.*, dbo.primaryTheme(STY.[Number], c.ProjectType) from CTE as c join Table STY on t.ID = c.id
```